# Converting JSON file to new CSV file using Python Script

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to convert JSON data into CSV format so I can import it into LibreCalc. I've found a pretty simple Python script that *almost* does what I'm looking for, but it doesn't quite work properly.

This is the script I've made, taken from snippets of code in the guide link. EDIT: I can't add the link as stack overflow thinks its spam.

```py
import json
import csv

#read file
with open('test.json', 'r') as jsonfile:
  data=jsonfile.read()

# parse file
jsonobj = json.loads(data)

def jsontocsv(input_json, output_path):
  keylist = []
  for key in jsonobj[0]:
    keylist.append(key)
    f = csv.writer(open(output_path, "w"))
    f.writerow(keylist)

  for record in jsonobj:
    currentrecord = []
    for key in keylist:
      currentrecord.append(record[key])
      f.writerow(currentrecord)



jsontocsv(jsonobj,'test.csv')
```

And this is the test JSON data, also taken from the links example.

```
[{
"Name" : "Bob",
"City" : "San Diego",
"State" : "CA"
},
{
"Name" : "Sue",
"City" : "San Francisco",
"State" : "CA"
},
{
"Name" : "Ted",
"City" : "New York",
"State" : "NY"
},
{
"Name" : "Joe",
"City" : "Miami",
"State" : "FL"
}]
```

When I run the script, instead of getting a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Name,City,State
Bob,San Diego,CA
Sue,San Francisco,CA
Ted,New York,NY
Joe,Miami,FL
```

I get this...

```
City,State,Name
San Diego
San Diego,CA
San Diego,CA,Bob
San Francisco
San Francisco,CA
San Francisco,CA,Sue
New York
New York,NY
New York,NY,Ted
Miami
Miami,FL
Miami,FL,Joe
```

I'm literally copying this guys code and following his example, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried playing with it a bit and changing the indenting etc, but nothing seems to work. I'm sure it's something ridiculously simple, and no doubt something I've messed up, but I can't figure it out.

Using my own JSON files with the actual data I want to convert has the same effect.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Let me note down your bug:

You have kept `f.writerow(keylist)` inside the loop. Basically, it is causing that for every key element that you append on keylist, it writes it down to the file.

**SOLUTION**: Simply put them outside the loop:

```
def jsontocsv(input_json, output_path):
  keylist = []
  for key in jsonobj[0]:
    keylist.append(key)
  f = csv.writer(open(output_path, "w"))
  f.writerow(keylist)

  for record in jsonobj:
    currentrecord = []
    for key in keylist:
      currentrecord.append(record[key])
    f.writerow(currentrecord)
```

You should be good to go :)

Answer (score 2):

### `pandas` is a quick and easy option:

- Given the data shown, in a file name `test.json`
- Load it into a `pandas.DataFrame`
- Save it to a `csv` format with `df.to_csv`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('test.json')

df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

#### DataFrame:

[image]

#### Saved `csv` file:

```
Name,City,State
Bob,San Diego,CA
Sue,San Francisco,CA
Ted,New York,NY
Joe,Miami,FL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
import csv

from operator import itemgetter

# Load json file
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Get keys of a dictionary within the loaded json data
# . The keys represent the headers of the CSV
headers = data[0].keys()
# Creater an itemgetter.
# . This will facilitate getting the values of our keys (aka headers)
values = itemgetter(*headers)

# Open file to write
with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
    # Create csv writer object
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # Write the header row
    writer.writerow(headers)

    for row in data:
        # values(row) will output the values of the dictionary
        # If you are in Python >3.7 you don't really need values()
        # . since the dictionaries are ordered.
        writer.writerow(values(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import csv

#read file
with open('test.json', 'r') as jsonfile:
    data = jsonfile.read()

# parse file
jsonobj = json.loads(data)

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')

    # Extract the header
    headers = list(jsonobj[0].keys())
    wr.writerow(headers)

    # Extract the value from list of dict 
    m = [[v for _, v in i.items()] for i in jsonobj]
    for k in m:
        wr.writerow(k)
```